# Strange Swift numbers type casting

Tags: swift, casting, type-inference

I've just noticed that Swift does some type casting over Int and Double.
When I try to evaluate

```
(10 / 3.0) - (10 / 3)
```

`0.333...` is expected, but it's actually `0.0`.
Could someone explain this please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, I also found this quite surprising. `Double` conforms to both `FloatLiteralConvertible` and `IntegerLiteralConvertible` (`ExpressibleByFloatLiteral` and `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` in Swift 3). Therefore a
`Double` can be initialized with *floating point literal*

```
let a = 3.0
```

or with an *integer literal*:

```
let b : Double = 10
```

(The same is true for other floating point types like `Float` and
`CGFloat`.)

Now it might be unexpected for all of us with an (Objective-)C background
that both statements

```
let x : Double = 10/4     // x = 2.5 .  Really? Yes!
let y = 10/4 as Double    // Same here ...
```

assign the value `0.25` to the variable. From the context, the result of the
division must be a `Double` and Swift does not implicitly convert types.
Therefore `/` *must* be the floating point division operator

```
func /(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double
```

so the compiler creates both arguments as `Double`s from the literals
"10" and "4". (If `10/4` were treated as the division of two integers
then the result would also be an integer, and that cannot be assigned
to a `Double`.)

Note that this is different from

```
let z = Double(10/4)   // z = 2.0 . (I just thought that I understood it &%$!?)
```

which does an integer division and converts the result to `Double`.
`Double` has an `init(_ v: Int)` constructor, and therefore `10/4`
*can* be treated as the division of two integers here.

It really looks a bit strange if we summarize these results:

```
let x : Double = 10/4     // x = 2.5 
let y = 10/4 as Double    // y = 2.5
let z = Double(10/4)      // z = 2.0
```

Now we can apply these results to your expression

```
(10 / 3.0) - (10 / 3)
```

The first part `(10 / 3.0)` can only be a `Double`, therefore `-`
must be the floating point subtraction operator

```
func -(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double
```

and thus `(10 / 3)` must also be a `Double`. Again, `/` must be the floating point division operator, so `10` and `3` are treated as `Double` constants.

Therefore the expression is equivalent to

```
(Double(10) / 3.0) - (Double(10) / Double(3))
```

and evaluates to `0.0`. If you change the expression to

```
(10 / 3.0) - Double(10 / 3)
```

then the result is `0.333...` because in this context, `10 / 3`
is the division of two integer constants, as explained above.