# Adding Ints and Double always needs conversion?

Tags: swift

If I'm going to do something like this:

```
var total = 0.05 * 6 + 9
```

Do I need to always do this for it to work?

```
var total = 0.05 * Double(6) + Double(9)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeric literals like `6` or `9` don't have a fixed type, they adapt automatically. So in `0.05 * 6 + 9`, `6` and `9` are already of type `Double`. If you wrote

```
let six = 6
let nine = 9
var total = 0.05 * six + nine
```

that wouldn't work, because the `6` on its own has type `Int`.

Comment: And sometimes the "automatic adaption" gives [unexpected results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813516/strange-swift-numbers-type-casting) :)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on gnasher729's answer, if you find yourself having to (say) add a `Double` and an `Int` frequently

e.g.

```
let six: Int = 6
let nine: Double = 9
var totalError = six + nine // Error!
```

You can add a function to do it to save typing

```
func +(lhs: Int, rhs: Double) -> Double
{
    return Double(lhs) + rhs
}

var total = six + nine // OK!
```

I don't think I'd recommend doing it in the general case though because the whole point of the original restriction is to make you think about the conversion as a source of potential errors.  The one case where I think it is totally legitimate is with shift operators

```
var foo: Int = 5
var bar: UInt64 = 20

var baz = bar << foo // Error!
```

In the above case, it is totally brain dead that foo needs to be cast to `UInt64` IMO, the right hand side of both shift operators should always be an `Int`.