# Math divison in Swift

Tags: swift, math, division

I'm trying to make a math app with different equations and formulas but I'm trying to  circle sector but i just wanted to try to divide the input value by 360 but when I do that it only says 0 unless the value is over 360. I have tried using String, Double and Float with no luck I don't know what I'm doing is wrong but down here is the code. I'm thankful for help but I have been sitting a while and searched online for an answer with no result I might have been searching with the wrong search.

```
if graderna.text == ""{
        }
        else{
            var myInt: Int? = Int(graderna.text!)    // conversion of string to Int
            var myInt2: Int? = Int(radien.text!)
            let pi = 3.1415926
            let lutning = 360


            let result = (Double(myInt! / lutning) * Double(pi))
            svar2.text = "\(result)"
        }
```

Comment: The type inference rules can be counter-intuitive: `Double(1/2)` gives `0.0`, but `1/2 as Double` gives `0.5` (compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813516/strange-swift-numbers-type-casting).

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is performing integer division, taking the integer result and converting it to a double. Instead, you want to convert these individual integers to doubles and then do the division. So, instead of

```
let result = (Double(myInt! / lutning) * Double(pi))
```

You should

```
let result = Double(myInt!) / Double(lutning) * Double(pi)
```

Note, `Double` already has a `.pi` constant, so you can remove your `pi` constant, and simplify the above to:

```
let result = Double(myInt!) / Double(lutning) * .pi
```

Personally, I’d define `myInt` and `lutning` to be `Double` from the get go (and, while we’re at it, remove all of the forced unwrapping (with the `!`) of the optionals):

```
guard
    let text = graderna.text,
    let text2 = radien.text,
    let value = Double(text),
    let value2 = Double(text2)
else {
    return
}

let lutning: Double = 360
let result = value / lutning * .pi
```

Or, you can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) to safely unwrap those optional strings:

```
guard
    let value = graderna.text.flatMap({ Double($0) }),
    let value2 = radien.text.flatMap({ Double($0) })
else {
    return
}

let lutning: Double = 360
let result = value / lutning * .pi
```

(By the way, if you’re converting between radians and degrees, it should be 2π/360, not π/360.)

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing an Int by an Int.

Integer division rounds to the nearest integer towards zero. Therefore for example 359 / 360 is not a number close to 1, it is 0. 360 / 360 up to 719 / 360 equals 1. 720 / 360 to 1079 / 360 equals 2, and so on.

But your use of optionals is atrocious. I'd write

```
let myInt = Int(graderna.text!)
let myInt2 = Int(radien.text!)

if let realInt = myInt, realInt2 = myInt2 {
    let pi = 3.1415926
    let lutning = 360.0

    let result = Double (realInt) * (pi / lutning)
    svar2.text = "\(result)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your timme and help aswell @gnasher729

Answer (score 0):

In the line `let result = (Double(myInt! / lutning) * Double(pi))` you cast your type to `double` *after* dividing two integers so your result will always be zero. You have to make them doubles *before* division.

`let result = (Double(myInt!) / Double(lutning)) * Double(pi))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value should be correct, then try as

```
let division = ((Float(V1) / Float(V2)) * Float(pi))
```