# Dividing UInt64 always returns 0

Tags: swift, math, int

```
let a: UInt64 = 17400000
let b: UInt64 = 27001916

let result = a / b

print(result)

print((a / b) * 100) //-> Also prints 0
```

**Why does result always print `0` and how can I get the real result?**

This probably seems very simple but I couldn't figure it out

Comment: Integer division always *truncates* the result.

Comment: Well how can I then print the real result?

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate, you need to convert the numbers to floating point numbers.

Comment: Here is another example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35383062/1187415

Comment: @MartinR Yes I already got it, but I can't mark this question as solved bc no one added an answer. You can't mark a comment as answer