# I can't get a decimal out of my equation. Trying to use progress bar

Tags: swift, progress-bar

I'm using a progress bar in my app to show how close someone is to reaching their savings goal. Here are my variables: (Note they are supposed to be in dollars.)

```
var amountToSave: Int = 100
var amountSavedSoFar: Int = 10
```

I've tried many equations that should work, but they either put out zero or over 1 which makes the progress bar go full. Here are some that I have tried:

```
var progress: Int = amountSavedSoFar/AmountToSave //puts out zero (should be 0.10)
```

I've also tried:

```
var progress: Int = 100*amountSavedSoFar/amountToSave //puts out over 1 (Progress Bar goes full)
```

Am I missing something? I tried the math outside xcode on a calculator and the first one I tried should be the one that works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Math divison in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383062/math-divison-in-swift)

Comment: 0.1 isn't an integer. Why are you assigning it to an integer if you want it to be a floating point value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Int , the result is Int

So you should use Double

```
var amountToSave: Double = 100.0

var amountSavedSoFar: Double = 10.0

var progress: Double = amountSavedSoFar/amountToSave

print(progress) //0.1
```

Comment: There's no need for the `: Double` on the three variables.

Answer (score -1):

Make it a double

```
var amountToSave: = 100.0
var amountSavedSoFar: = 10.0
```

Also, I would suggest using a cocoa pod called "Money"
https://github.com/danthorpe/Money

Comment: Those are still `Int`.