# Wrong result with a division in Swift

Tags: swift, int, double

Weirdly, this :

```
print(Double(414/90))
```

returns 4.0 when it should return 4.6.

My guess is that swift rounds the result to the lowest, but why 4.0 and not 4.6? Isn't that the point of casting it as an Integer ? How can I switch off that rounding thing ?

Fixed : Swift consider 414 as Integers, so you should =

```
print(Double(414.00/90.00))
```

Comment: My guess is that `414/90` does integer division, yielding `4`, which you then cast to `Double`, giving `4.0`.

Comment: Oh boy you're right. Fixed it :
    print(Double(414/90))

Comment: Have a look at [Strange Swift numbers type casting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813516/strange-swift-numbers-type-casting) for some thoughts about int/double conversions. Would you have guessed that `print(414/90 as Double)` prints `4.6`?