# How are Swift array types treated differently from assignment to operator?

Tags: swift

Is there a different policy for type inference when assigning variables vs. binary operator?

```
let arrayOfInts = [1,2,3]
let arrayOfDoubles = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
// arrayOfInts == arrayOfDoubles 
// Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to ... [Int] [Double]
[1,2,3] == [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] // works?
```

Comment: Maybe the literals are being up-cast to `[NSNumber]` or `[Double]`, but I don't know why.

Comment: Simpler example without arrays: `1.0 == 1` compiles, but `let x = 1.0; let y = 1; x == y` doesn't.

Comment: But have a look at [Strange Swift numbers type casting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813516/strange-swift-numbers-type-casting) where it is shown that type inference in Swift sometimes works differently from what might be expected (compared with other languages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `arrayOfInts`, the compiler by default infers the integer literals to be of type `Int`. Thus `arrayOfInts` is an `[Int]`. With `arrayOfDoubles`, the compiler will by default infer the floating point literals to be of type `Double`. Thus `arrayOfDoubles` is of type `[Double]`. You cannot compare a `[Int]` with a `[Double]` (at least not with the standard library's overloads of `==`), therefore you'll get a compiler error.

However, with the expression `[1, 2, 3] == [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]` – Swift can infer *both* the floating point and integer literals to be of type `Double`, as `Double` conforms to both [`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral) and [`ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebyfloatliteral). Therefore you're comparing a `[Double]` with a `[Double]` – which *is* legal.