# Need help on type inference in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, type-inference

when i was reading about type inference in swift i came to know that swift is smart enough to know about data types

like when i write this program

```
var v3 = 2+2.5
print("the result is \(v3)")
```

then i see output

```
the result is 4.5
```

but when i write this program

```
var v1 = 2.5
var v2 = 2
var v3:Double = v1 + v2
print("the result is \(v3)")
```

then it gives me this error

```
ERROR at line 7, col 20: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int'
var v3:Double = v1 + v2
                ~~ ^ ~~
NOTE at line 7, col 20: expected an argument list of type '(Double, Double)'
var v3:Double = v1 + v2
```

so can anyone explain me what is going on here

i have done this program on IBM sandbox

Comment: Remotely related: [Strange Swift numbers type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813516/strange-swift-numbers-type-casting/28813749#28813749)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `var v3 = 2+2.5` Swift has to infer the type of `2`, a numeric literal compatible both with `Int` and `Double`. The compiler is able to do so, because there's `2.5` in the same expression, which is a `Double`. Hence, the compiler concludes that `2` must also be a `Double`. The compiler computes the sum, and sets `v3` to `4.5`. No addition is performed at runtime.

When you write `var v2 = 2` the compiler treats `2` as an `Int`, making `v1` and `Int` as well. Now there is an addition on the `var v3:Double = v1 + v2`, which fails because `v1` and `v2` have mismatched types.

If you declare `var v2:Double = 2` instead, the problem will be fixed.

Comment: ok but why i have to do that why it should be same for variables and not for numeric literals

Comment: @RahulGUsai Because variables have one specific type given to them at the declaration, while numerical literal type depends on the context. If you do `var v3 = v1 + 2` in the second example, Swift will quietly interpret `2` as a `Double` based on the context of the expression in which it is used.

Comment: like you said above that  If you do var v3 = v1 + 2 in the second example, Swift will quietly interpret 2 as a Double based on the context of the expression in which it is used.                                                                                    but when i write this then why swift fails to infere the type                                                                                                                                                                                            var v1 = "456"
var v2 = 123 + v1

Comment: @RahulGUsai This is because `String` is not among possible types for numeric literal `123`.