# Why does swift conversion work for floating point division?

Tags: swift, casting, type-conversion, division, integer-division

Like in many languages, Swift's division operator defaults to integer division, so:

```
let n = 1 / 2
print(n) // 0
```

If you want floating point division, you have to do

```
let n1 = 1.0 / 2
let n2 = 1 / 2.0
let n3 = Double(1) / 2
let n4 = 1 / Double(2)

print(n1) // 0.5
print(n2) // 0.5
print(n3) // 0.5
print(n4) // 0.5
```

Again, like most other languages, you can't cast the whole operation:

```
let n5 = Double(1 / 2)
print(n5) // 0.0
```

Which happens because swift performs the integer division of 1 and 2 (`1 / 2`) and gets 0, which it then tries to cast to a `Double`, effectively giving you 0.0.

I am curious as to why the following works:

```
let n6 = (1 / 2) as Double
print(n6) // 0.5
```

I feel like this should produce the same results as `Double(1 / 2)`. Why doesn't it?

Comment: `Double(1 / 2)` is *not* a cast; it's a *conversion* from `Int` to `Double`. No such conversion takes place for `(1 / 2) as Double`, the integer literals are simply inferred to be doubles. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/28813516/2976878

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange Swift numbers type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813516/strange-swift-numbers-type-casting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1` and `2` are literals. They have no type unless you give them a type from context.

```
let n6 = (1 / 2) as Double
```

is essentially the same as

```
let n6: Double = 1 / 2
```

that means, you tell the compiler that the result is a `Double`. That means the compiler searches for operator `/` with a `Double` result, and that means it will find the operator `/` on two `Double` operands and therefore considers both literals as of type `Double`.

On the other hand,

```
let n5 = Double(1 / 2)
```

is a cast (or better said, initialization of a `Double`). That means the expression `1 / 2` gets evaluated first and then converted to `Double`.

Comment: `Double(1 / 2)` is not a cast; casting is done with `as(!/?)` ;)

Comment: @Hamish I know but the syntax is so close to static casts in some languages that I am not worrying about that too much :)

Comment: `1 and 2 are literals. They have no type unless you give them a type from context.` I thought all integer literals default to `Int` if no type is provided?

Comment: @JAL Yes, but `as Double` provides the type to the expression.

Comment: @JAL I have just realized what you meant :)