# Is the Swift divide "/" operator not working or have I missed something?

Tags: swift, operators

I am trying to initialise the following array of fractions in a Swift playground

```
var probabilitiesX = Array(repeating: Double(1/36), count: 36)
```

but my output array is:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

basically all zeros. If I type in the fraction as a decimal "0.02777777" then I get the correct output however I am using various fractions and ideally do not want to have to type them all out.
Any ideas?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/28813516/2976878. You could do `[Double](repeating: 1 / 36, count: 36)` instead, where the integer literals are inferred to be `Double`s from context, or just use floating-point literals (`1.0 / 36.0`) which are inferred to be `Double` by default.

Comment: You can also annotate the type like this: `1/36 as Double`

Comment: @vacawama - I think you should post this as a separate answer, since A) it isn't obvious it should work (at least to me - I assumed it would do the division first) and B) it *does* work!

Comment: @Grimxn, I posted it as an answer.  Check it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is here: `1/36`. Both **1** and **36** are `Int`s. Try this:

```
var probabilitiesX = Array(repeating: 1.0 / 36.0, count: 36)
```

Comment: `1.0/36.0` is a `Double`, so no need for `Double()`.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that you are aware of the fact that `1/36` produces `0` because of integer division. This is probably why you wrote `Double(1/36)` to make Swift treat `1/36` as a double.

However, Swift evaluates the expression in a different order than you think. Swift will evaluate `1/36` first, then evaluate `Double(0)`.

If you want to use `Double.init` in your code, you can do it like this:

```
Double(1)/Double(36)
```

Now, both 1 and 36 are converted to a double *before* the division. Therefore, no integer division occurs.

In fact, you don't need `Double` at all, just do:

```
1.0 / 36.0
```

Both `1.0` and `36.0` are `Double` literals.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have noted, the problem is that the `1` and `36` are inferred to be of type `Int`, so `1/36` is performed using integer divide with a result of `0`.  That is then passed to `Double()` which creates a `Double` from the `0`.

There are a number of ways you could fix this:

1. **Use floating point literals which will be inferred to be `Double`s:**

   ```
   var probabilitiesX = Array(repeating: 1.0/36.0, count: 36)
   ```

   You can get away with only using a floating point literal for one of them because Swift will infer that the other has to be a `Double` for divide to work:

   ```
   var probabilitiesX = Array(repeating: 1/36.0, count: 36)
   ```

   or

   ```
   var probabilitiesX = Array(repeating: 1.0/36, count: 36)
   ```
2. **Convert either or both of `1` and `36` to `Double`:**

   ```
   var probabilitiesX = Array(repeating: Double(1)/36, count: 36)
   ```

   or

   ```
   var probabilitiesX = Array(repeating: 1/Double(36), count: 36)
   ```

   or

   ```
   var probabilitiesX = Array(repeating: Double(1)/Double(36), count: 36)
   ```
3. **Cast `1/36` with `as Double`:**

   ```
   var probabilitiesX = Array(repeating: 1/36 as Double, count: 36)
   ```

   In this case, since Swift knows the result of the division is a `Double`, it is able to infer that `1` and `36` are `Double`s because the only version of division that results in a `Double` is the one that takes two `Double`s as input.
4. **Tell Swift you are creating a `[Double]`:**

   ```
   var probabilitiesX = [Double](repeating: 1/36, count: 36)
   ```

   or

   ```
   var probabilitiesX: [Double] = Array(repeating: 1/36, count: 36)
   ```

   In this case, since Swift knows the array contains `Double`, then it is able to infer that `1/36` is a `Double` and like #3 it then infers that `1` and `36` are `Double`s as well because the only version of division that results in a `Double` is the one that takes two `Double`s as input.