# How does Swift's int literal to float inference work?

Tags: swift, type-inference, implicit-conversion

Swift can infer int literals to be doubles or floats

```
let x: Float = 3
```

It even works with arithmetic. It will convert everything before doing the math, so this is also 3:

```
let y: Float = 5/2 + 0.5
```

But what are the actual rules for this? There are ambiguous situations, for example if the inference is for a parameter:

```
func foobar(_ x: Int) -> Int {
  return x
}

func foobar(_ x: Float) -> Float {
  return y
}

foobar(1/2)
```

In this case it infers it as an int and returns 0, but if you delete the first function it switches to a float and returns 0.5.

What are the rules? Where is it documented?

Even more annoying is when Swift *could* infer it as a float but doesn't

```
func foobar(_ x: Float) -> Float {
   return x
}

let x = 1/2
foobar(x) // Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Float'
```

Comment: Related: [Strange Swift numbers type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28813516/1187415): `1` and `2` can be both integer literals and floating point literals.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe the ambiguity case is officially documented – but the rule is that the compiler prefers to use the default type for a literal where it can. The default type being `Int` for an integer literal and `Double` for a floating-point literal (glossing over `IntegerLiteralType`). When ranking solutions, the compiler assigns a score to each to work out which it should favour (higher score is worse), and "non-default literal" [is a component of that score](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/82d07ad88d392bd45d87622cc71b7389e99db104/lib/Sema/ConstraintSystem.h#L450).

Comment: Re: your last example – Swift doesn't infer types across multiple statements (the constraint solver operates on a single expression with a potential contextual type to convert the expression type to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Swift behaviors at play here:

1. Swift can infer an int *literal* as *type* float if needed (or double)
2. Each literal has a *default type* that is used if inference fails. The type for int literals is `Int`

With only one function, rule 1 applies. It sees that a float is needed, so it infers the division as float division and the int literals as floats:

```
func foobar(_ x: Float) -> Float {
  return y
}
foobar(1/2) // 0.5
```

If you overload the function, rule 1 no longer works. The type is now ambiguous so it falls back to the default type of `Int`, which luckily matches one of the definitions:

```
func foobar(_ x: Int) -> Int {
  return x
}
func foobar(_ x: Float) -> Float {
  return y
}
foobar(1/2)  // 0
```

See what happens if you make it so the default no longer works. Neither rule applies so you get an error:

```
func foobar(_ x: Double) -> Double {
  return x
}
func foobar(_ x: Float) -> Float {
  return y
}
foobar(1/2)  // Ambiguous use of operator '/'
```

Comment: For all practical purposes the default type of an integer literal is `Int`, but just for fun it's worth noting that it's actually defined by the (undocumented) top-level type `IntegerLiteralType`, which can be changed by the user. Try defining `typealias IntegerLiteralType = Double` and seeing what happens with your last example :)

Answer (score 1):

Literals don't have a type as such. The docs say,

> If there isn’t suitable type information available, Swift infers that the
>   literal’s type is one of the default literal
>   types defined in the Swift standard library. The default types are Int
>   for integer literals, Double for floating-point literals, String for
>   string literals, and Bool for Boolean literals.

So unless your argument explicity says anything other than `Int`, it will infer integer literals as `Int`.

---

Refer this for more information, [Lexical Structure - Literals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#).

Comment: Ah, the overloaded function makes its type ambiguous, so it picks the default type, so it finds the matching declaration.

Answer (score 0):

By default, passing in `1/2` as your argument, you are performing a calculation on two *Integers* which will evaluate to a result of type *Integer* thus the first function being used.

To have a *Float*, one or all of the arguments have to be of type `Float` so either `1.0/2` or `1/2.0` or `1.0/2.0`. This will cause the second function to run instead.

In `let x = 1/2`, x is inferred to be of type `Int` because both `1` and `2` are of type *Int*.

Swift will not try to infer a *Float* if not indicated.