# Literal Int to Double coercion in arithmetic expressions

Tags: swift, math, type-coercion

It appears that Swift applies floating point contagion (as it is called in other languages) to literal Int operands in an expression containing a Double variable before evaluating the expression. Is there an explicit statement about that somewhere? I wasn't able to find a specific description about what to expect.

For example, suppose I have `let b = 0.14`. Then the following all yield the same result. (I am working with Swift 5.0.1.)

```
 19> 5.0 * b / 6.0
$R12: Double = 0.11666666666666668
 20> 5 * b / 6
$R13: Double = 0.11666666666666668
 21> 5 / 6 * b
$R14: Double = 0.11666666666666668
 22> b * 5 / 6
$R15: Double = 0.11666666666666668
 23> (5 / 6) * b
$R16: Double = 0.11666666666666668
 24> b * (5 / 6)
$R17: Double = 0.11666666666666668
```

That's great, it seems to make it easier to predict what the result will be, since it appears to be insensitive to the order of operations. (Incidentally that behavior differs from some other languages, I'm pretty sure.) However, I wasn't able to find any explicit statement about what should be expected in the case of literal Int operands mixed with a Double variable; I looked at these pages in hope of finding something: [Expressions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html), [Basic Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html), [Advanced Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html). Can anyone point to a spec which describes what to expect in such cases?

Comment: `Double` conforms to both `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral` and `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` (and the compiler infers the “right” one from the context, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/28813516/1187415).

Comment: See also https://forums.swift.org/t/string-literal-not-inferred-to-staticstring/30154/7 in the Swift forum: *“The compiler treats Double as an alternative literal type for ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral.”*

Comment: @MartinR Yes, the key to the problem is how Swift applies the context to determine the right kind of operand. You've already given a great answer in [Strange Swift numbers type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813516/strange-swift-numbers-type-casting) so I've marked this question as a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears that Swift applies floating point contagion

It doesn't, actually. It appears that way, because `Double` conforms to [`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral), which explains why this is possible:

```
let double: Double = 1
```

but not:

```
let i: Int = 1
print(i * 1.23) // error: binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double'
```

Comment: I dunno, I think a more crucial aspect is how Swift decides that it needs to interpret the integer literal as a float. That aspect is addressed in the accepted answer to [Strange Swift numbers type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813516/strange-swift-numbers-type-casting).

Comment: @RobertDodier Ah, good find, that's a good answer. Yep, it just boils down to the overload resolution of the operators, and how the type inference system is free to pick any `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` type as is appropriate to satisfy the operators.