# Understanding the Doubles and Ints in Swift

Tags: swift, int, double

I thought I had a good understanding about Doubles and Ints until I accidentally ran into the following code.

### To my surprise the following code works just fine.

```
let amounts = [50, 5.0, 10]
var total = 0.0

for i in 0..<amounts.count {
  total += amounts[i]

  print("Total: \(total)")
}
```

... but it stops working if I change the `5.0` to `10` or a `50` or even to `5` and generates the following error.

> > error: binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int'

Can someone tell me why is that the code doesn't break when mixing `50`, `5.0` and  `10`? I was under the impression that this wouldn't work.

Comment: Does this question/answer answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58718608/3141234

Comment: Also related: [Strange Swift numbers type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28813516/1187415).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, Swift is very strict with types, but there's one area where it's not so strict - literals. `Double` conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`, so you could do:

```
let x: Double = 1 // "1" is "magically" converted to a Double!?
```

and have it compile. The same with arrays - the compiler thinks that the array literal that you have:

```
[50, 5.0, 10]
```

is a `[Double]`, because it can convert both `50` and `10` to `Double`. It can't be an `[Int]` because `5.0` can't be converted to an `Int` (`Int` does not conform to `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`)

The line:

```
total += amounts[i]
```

only works when both sides are of the same type. Note that here, the compiler will not try to convert from `Int` to `Double` because the expressions involved (`total` and `amounts[i]`) are not literals!

If you change the array literal to `[50, 10, 10]`, all elements are `Int`, so the compiler infers the array to be `[Int]`, and `amount[i]` becomes an `Int`, causing the line to fail compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in Swift can hold elements of a single type, so when you mix `50, 5.0, 10` the compiler will infer the `Array` is of type `Double`

In the working code, the array is an array of `[Doubles]` when you change 5.0 to 10 the array is of `[Int]` that because of swift Type Inference.

Thus

Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int'

[image]

Comment: This explains the symptom, but not the cause

Comment: BTW you can use back ticks for highlighting code `like this`, instead of **bolding**.

Comment: Thanks for the backticks hint. I have updated the answer,

Answer (score 1):

Swift Compiler don't know operation about two different data-type like Int and Double.

So you can achieve this by type cast from Int to Double using this Code.

```
  let amounts = [50, 5, 10]
var total = 0.0

for i in 0..<amounts.count {
    total = total + Double(amounts[i])

  print("Total: \(total)")
}
```

Comment: I know how to cast types, my question was why it was working with mixed types. See other answers.