# Why is x / 100 == 0 when x != 0 in swift?

Tags: swift, for-loop, math, operators, division

I have created a for loop in which I calculate a few values.

```
for i in 1...100{
  let xValue = i/100
  print(xValue) // returns 0 every time except when i == 100
}
```

This is a recreation of a part of that for loop. Why is it that I do not get the right value for 'xValue'?

For info I have also tried the following:

```
let xValue: Float = Float(i/100)
```

And that doesn't work either, despite me being very specific. I must have forgotten something basic about these arithmetic
operators in swift.

Comment: Try `Float(i)/100`

Comment: You'll need `let xValue: Float = Float(i) / 100` instead.

Comment: `Float(i/100)` takes `i/100`, which is 0 because they are both `Int`s, then converts it into a `Float` of `0.0`

Comment: Somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28813516/1187415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `i` and `100` are both integer values, `/` will do integer division and the result will be truncated to 0.

Even when you do `let xValue: Float = Float(i/100)`, the result of division inside the parentheses is already truncated to 0 before the value can be converted to a Float.

Convert `i` to a floating-point value before dividing to prevent the result from being truncated.

```
for i in 1...100{
  let xValue = Float(i)/100
  print(xValue)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you divide an `Int` by an `Int`, the result will be *rounded down*. Use a floating point type, like `Double` or `Float` for more precision.

```swift
for i in 1...100 {
  let xValue = Float(i)/100
  print(xValue)
}
```

To address your attempted solution - when you do:

```swift
let xValue: Float = Float(i/100)
```

The `Int` result is first computed in `i/100` (and rounded down to 0) then you are casting to a `Float`.
Therefore, we cast `i` to a `Float` before the division so the result is computed as a `Float`.

Comment: `Double` is more precise than a `Float` unless you use `Float80`.